# google drive php libarary issue

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

i am creating folder inside google drive with php google drive library, currently i am settings its permission to anyone, which is not that i need i want only person who is owner of that drive who gave his credentials in json file can read or a specific email that i am allowing this
chatgpt did not give any correct solution, please help me regrading this.
here is code

```
$driveService = initialize_google_drive_client();
        $folder_name = 'test123';
        // Define the folder metadata
        $folderMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
            'name' => $folder_name,
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        ]);
        // Create the folder in Google Drive
        $folder = $driveService->files->create($folderMetadata, [
            'fields' => 'id',
        ]);
        if ($folder) {
            // Set permissions for the folder to make it public
            $permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission([
                'type' => 'anyone',
                'role' => 'reader',
            ]);
            $driveService->permissions->create($folder->id, $permission);
        }
```

chatgpt code is here

```
if ($folder) {
    // Remove any existing permissions for 'anyone' (optional)
    $driveService->permissions->delete($folder->id, 'anyone');
    // Set permissions for specific email addresses
    $emailAddresses = ['user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com'];
    foreach ($emailAddresses as $email) {
        $permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission([
            'type' => 'user',
            'role' => 'writer', // You can also use 'reader' or other roles as needed.
            'emailAddress' => $email,
        ]);
        $driveService->permissions->create($folder->id, $permission);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions

Comment: The chatGPT suggestion looks plausible. What exact problem did you have when you used that?

Comment: can you provide me some php example please

Comment: The PHP code shouldn't really be any different, you only need to set the the different types of permissions, as listed in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Your doing it wrong credentials.json should be created by **you** the developer its against googles TOS to be giving out your credentials.json.

credentials.json is not linked to a user it is linked to a project on google developer console and is used to request authorization of a user.

The user who authenticates the app and grants it permissions to access their data, is the user who will be creating files so you should not need to set permissions on them.